Different name mangling for std::string using different C++ compilers
I am playing with demangling and I noticed that for std::string the mangled name depends on the compiler in use. For example, this simple program:
#include <cxxabi.h>
#include <iostream>
#include <string>

int main(){
  std::cout << typeid(std::string).name() << std::endl;
  return 0;
}

compiled under CentOS 7 using g++ 7.3.1 (from devtoolset-7) with --std=c++14 returns:
Ss

while under Ubuntu 18.04 with g++ 7.5.0 with the same flag:
NSt7__cxx1112basic_stringIcSt11char_traitsIcESaIcEEE

I don't understand what determines the different behavior, since the two compiler versions are pretty similar. The only thing that comes to my mind is that maybe it could be due to different versions of libstdc++, but I can't figure out the underlying reason.

Name mangling is compiler-specific, not dictated by the standard or the platform. A compiler uses whatever mangling it needs. Even for the same compiler vendor, there could be differences between versions. Not much to understand about that, its an implementation detail

One thing to note is that these are both valid Itanium ABI manglings. Ss is a shortcut for the mangled form of std::string. Even the second output uses the similar Sa shortcut for std::allocator.

It could even be a UUID string, or a hash value.  It could even be stripped out, so it would be empty string for every type.  It may vary from build-to-build, or even from run-to-run.  In my opinion, at best it is only useful as a developer aid, not as a mechanism to do (say) serialization/deserialization for identifying types.

See https://gcc.gnu.org/onlinedocs/libstdc++/manual/using_dual_abi.html

As a side note, boost has a type_index.hpp which provides functions to pretty-print typenames: boost::typeindex::type_id<T>().pretty_name(); or boost::typeindex::type_id_runtime(object).pretty_name(). That way, you can leave the damangling-knowledge to the author of that library, and focus on your actual project :-)

@Cristian Stieber Many thanks for the tip, I'll check it out!

That's completely expected. typeid names are implementation defined and are not required to be identical across different implementations or even between different versions of the same implementation (compiler). They are also not required to be equal to the mangled names.

@NicolaMori Some good documentation. Note the wording No guarantees are given.  That's pretty damning, but most implementations do their best to provide sensible and unique names, but portability of the names seems to be a low priority.

typeid names are also not required to be the same as the mangled name (assuming mangled names exist at all).

The mangled names are decoded as follows:
Ss is ::std::basic_string<char,::std::char_traits<char>,::std::allocator<char>>
NSt7__cxx1112basic_stringIcSt11char_traitsIcESaIcEEE is ::std::__cxx11::basic_string<char,::std::char_traits<char>,::std::allocator<char>>
The second type is in a different namespace. This is due to how libstdc++ managed the C++11 ABI break for std::string.
The C++ standard does not say what the actual type of std::string is, and there is no ABI specification for this either, so there may be inline namespaces or typedefs involved when you write std::string.

"The mangled names are decoded as follows" - only on systems conforming to the Itanium ABI..
